# Sum of Sum gives Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel I want to SUM a few numbers. Everything works until I add a cell that is a sum itself, then I get 0.

For example:

```
=SUM(A1)    => 15
=SUM(A2)    => 23
=SUM(A1:A2) => 38
=SUM(A1,A2,A3) => I get 0, but I want 76
```

As you can see, I am able to SUM non-sum cells, but when I try to incorporate a sum cell, I get zero, but I want it to give me 15+23+38=76.

***How do I sum cells with sums?***

--

This also happens when I don't use SUM: `=A1+A2+A3   => 0`

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. What happens if you try: `=SUM(A1:A3) => 38`?

Comment: Try to provide the problem file, it will be more helpful.

Comment: I can only assume that one of your lines is actually `‐38` and being added to your other lines which total 38. 38 + (-38) = 0 and would be correct. A screenshot or the contents of the rows themselves would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing wrong wit `=SUM(A1,A2,A3)` or this even  `15+23+38`,, as you have written that **but when I try to incorporate a sum cell, I get zero**, I guess that you are violating Circular Reference ,,,, possibly formula is in cell, has been used to SUM, Please [edit] your post & share the Screen Shot with us !!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a circular reference with one of the subtotals.  I had accidentally included the sum row in the group of cells to total which was causing the error.

So in the example above, I had:

```
=SUM(A1:A3) => 38
```

A3 being the circular reference.